# Google map in bootstrap css

Tags: css, google-maps, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to load a map in the second section of this page

http://lowcoupling.appspot.com/anotherMapPage.html

As you can see the problem is that the map is depicted as a 1px line

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you want height for map div in percentage??
I you add fix height like "200px" map is visible...

Comment: @VinitaRathore He probably wants a fluid layout.

Comment: fluid layout in terms of height ?? If you resize window than also it is visible with same size.

Comment: the min-height of a section is set to calc(100% - 1px); I'd like the map to have the same height of a section. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

You are using `height:100%` to make the map as high as your `section` is - where you calculate `min-height: calc(100% - 1px);`. 
But you have bootstrap `row` element between, **which does not have a set `height`**, so your map does not have **a direct parent element to calculate it's `width` from** - so it takes `1px` - which is already set by default by bootstrap (`min-height:1px` - to keep columns in place).

You need to have a direct parent element which has a set `height` (that is not defined in percentages) to have the map expand to 100% of it's height.

If the `row` element that wraps your map would have a fixed height, your map container would expand to 100% of that height.

See example with direct parent using `calc(100% - 1px)`:
http://jsfiddle.net/LDzSk/1/